# How to Adding trigger to update quantity of tblProduct whenever user order a list of product

Tags: sql, triggers

My Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTSSU.png)

I want to Adding a list of product into tblOrderDetails, after that trigger auto update quantity into tblProduct

Comment: Which DBMS you are using. There is stonf possibility that this query `SELECT quantity FROM tblOrderDetails WHERE productId = tblProducts.productId` is returning more than one  row so so need to group by etc.

Comment: Yes, for sure that inner select is return more than 1 row. So, what are you trying do do for cases where more than one row is returned?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, when you use a subquery as an expression (i.e Quantity - () it can only return one result. Suppose you have two rows in order details, one with a quantity of 2 and one with a quantity of 3, there is no way for SQL Server to know which one you want to deduct. You need to make the subquery only return one row using an aggregate, or `TOP 1`.

**HOWEVER**, based on what I think your trigger is trying to do, it is actually very likely you don't want to reference `tblOrderDetails` at all, you are probably more interested in the memory resident table `inserted`, as any existing rows have presumably already been counted in the quantity, so you would actually want something like:

```
UPDATE  p
SET     p.Quantity = p.Quantity - i.Quantity
FROM    dbo.tblProducts AS p
        INNER JOIN 
         (  SELECT  productId, Quantity = SUM(Quantity)
            FROM    inserted 
            GROUP BY ProductId
        ) AS i 
            ON i.productId = p.productId
```

*N.B. I have included the schema prefix, and added table aliases, both good practices to start doing yourself*

**HOWEVER** managing quantities like this is not really a good idea, unless you have a very busy OLTP environment with millions of records and calculating this on the fly is having an impact on performance. It is usually much better to manage quantities using calculations, based on transactions (orders in/out). For ease of explanation, I will assume that you have two separate order tables, one for buying products and adding them to then inventory, and one for selling products, and removing them from the inventory.

So you might end up with something like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ProductInventory 
AS
SELECT  p.ProductID,
        p.Name,
        QuantityBought = ISNULL(b.Quantity, 0),
        QuantitySold = ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0),
        Quantity = ISNULL(b.Quantity, 0) - ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0)
FROM    dbo.tblProducts AS p
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  productId, Quantity = SUM(Quantity)
            FROM    dbo.tblOrderDetails 
            GROUP BY ProductId
        ) AS s
            ON s.productId = p.productId
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  productId, Quantity = SUM(Quantity)
            FROM    dbo.tblSupplierOrders -- OR whatever your table is for orders in 
            GROUP BY ProductId
        ) AS b
            ON b.productId = p.productId;
```

As a final aside, although it is somewhat personal preference, there is really no need to prefix your objects with their type (tblProduct, tblOrderDetails). There are two reasons for this, it is either obvious from the context what an object is (i.e you can't EXECUTE a table, and you can't select a procedure), or it is irrelevant (i.e. it doesn't matter if an object is a table or a view, what matters is the columns it returns). I have changed views to tables and vice versa in the past, and this would either mean having to rename the object, or keeping the incorrect prefix. It is much better to just leave as `Products` or `OrderDetails`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i got that. adding Top 1. i can get the quantity of order that i want to update tblProducts. You are saving me this time
`CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateQuantityProduct ON tblOrderDetails AFTER INSERT AS
 BEGIN
  UPDATE p
  SET  p.quantity = p.quantity - i.quantity 
  FROM tblProducts As p Inner JOIN ( SELECT  top 1(orderId), productId, quantity
          FROM  tblOrderDetails 
          order by orderId desc) as i on i.productId = p.productId
 
 END`

Comment: What you are doing won't work and will lead to incorrect updates. If you insert more than one row into tblOrderDetails at a time. The update I have given you using the memory resident table `inserted` seems like it would do what you want, and deal with multiple rows. Is there a reason you don't want to use that?

Comment: yeah ! i find new bug, When 1 insert a lot of item in tblOrderDetail. it only change the quantity of the last item into tblProducts